# How to write this in spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus

$$\iiint_K \frac{4z}{(1+\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2}} dxdydz$$

where $$r \in [1,2]$$ $$\theta \in [\frac{3 \pi}{4},\frac{7 \pi}{4}]$$ $$\phi \in [0, \pi]$$ $$|J| = r^2 \sin \phi$$

the integral - even without the limits - is zero.

$$\iiint \frac{4z}{(1+\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2}} dxdydz = \iiint \frac{4r \cos \phi r^2 \sin \phi}{(1+\frac{(r^2 \sin^2 \phi \cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta)}{r^2}} r dr d\theta d\phi = 0.$$

What am I missing out here?

**EDIT**: I still need some help here though.. 
I saw that my limits for  $\phi$ is wrong. It should be $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

And this integral should not be equal to zero. So.. HOW to solve this?

Comment: "the function - even without the limits - is zero" - I'm having a hard time understanding what you're saying here.

Comment: ©user170231 gahhh, hehe, I mean the integral*

Comment: Where did the $r$ before the $dr$ come from? And on the denominator you've got to simplify by $\sin^2 + \cos^2 =1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician where can you even find $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$ ? Have I substituted it wrong then?

Comment: On the denominator, the second term reduces to $\sin^2 \phi$.

Answer (score 1):

As this is spherical coordinates, the $r$'s in your integral should be $\rho$'s.  Also, you have an extra $r$ in your numerator.

Starting at where you left off:  $$\iiint \frac{4\rho \cos \phi \rho^2 \sin \phi}{1+\frac{\rho^2 \sin^2 \phi \cos^2 \theta + \rho^2 \sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta}{\rho^2}} \; d\rho d\theta d\phi = \iiint \frac{4\rho^3 \cos \phi \sin \phi}{1+\frac{\rho^2 \sin^2 \phi }{\rho^2}} \; d\rho  d\theta  d\phi = \iiint \frac{2\rho^3 \sin \left(2\phi\right)}{1+\sin^2 \phi} \; dr d\theta d\phi$$

Now split the triple integral because the bounds are not dependent on a variable and you can separate the integrand into three functions dependent only one one of the three variables:
$$\int_1^2 2\rho^3 \; d\rho \cdot \int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{7\pi}{4}}  d\theta \cdot \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin \left(2\phi\right)}{1+\sin^2 \phi} \; d\phi$$

The first two integrals are simple, and the third one is too with the proper substitution.  Let $u=1+\sin^2{\phi}$ so that $\frac{du}{\underbrace{2\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi}}_{sin{\left(2\phi\right)}}}=dx$:
$$\int_1^2 \frac{du}{u} = \ln{2}$$
Putting this all together yields $\frac{15}{2} \cdot \pi \cdot \ln{2}= \boxed{\frac{15 \pi \ln{2}}{2}}$

Comment: is it to much to ask, if you want to share how to solve the last $\int_0^{\pi}$ integral. Even though you say that I should substitute with $u$, I don't really get it.

Comment: I edited my answer briefly showing it @Felicia

Comment: Why do we have to change the limits to $\frac{\pm \pi}{2}$?

Comment: $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi$

Comment: One thing though.. I think the limits in the beginning shouldn't be $\phi \in [0,\pi]$ it should be $\frac{\pi }{2}$.. And with the $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin 2 \phi}{1+sin^2 \phi} d \phi = 0$. The whole original function should be equal to 0 then????? Is that even right?

Comment: I used the bounds that you provided.  And yes, I suppose.

Comment: I don't think that is right.. I checked with WolframAlpha and the answer should be equal to $\ln$ something.

Comment: You didn't provide the whole problem so I can't check

Comment: True that.. do you want me to post it here? I can do it as a link?

Comment: Well is the answer $\frac{15\pi \ln{2}}{2}$?

Comment: The $D$-area is: $(x^2+y^2+z^2) \le [0,4]. x+y \le 0 , z \ge 0$

Comment: Yes it is.. but how is it possible when the \int_pi/2 sin- integral is 0?

Comment: If the upper bound is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then it is not 0, I'll update my answer.